# BPM Project Scope And Boundaries

Tags: camunda, business-process-management

In my organization we used Camunda as our Enterprise BPM Engine. But we used Camunda only for a particular business problem. In an organization there will be lot of business units. For example, if we take insurance industry, there will be a department to process claims, another one to issue policies, another for account management etc. I dont think that the roles and responsibilities across all these departments are the same.Given the case do we start separate BPM projects by department or should there on BPM project shared across multiple departments?

Comment: This is a really subjective question.  Keeping things separate might cause more work, but should bring more clarity.  Consolidating might reduce overhead and work, but might bring confusion "I don't think that the roles and responsibilities across all these departments are the same".  I'd recommend starting with things separate and evaluate the overhead over time.

Comment: Thanks @user3112728. That helps, yes it is a subjective question. I am leaning towards going with embedded architecture to keep operations of the projects separate and planning on using optimize to tie things together